# How do you undisable in viewport all object in a collection?

Tags: outliner, collections, visibility

I have a complex scene I moved from 2.79 to 2.81. What makes it complex is that it has lots of objects as childs of other objects. Think complex folder tree. Basically hundred folders and each have their own sub folder structure. For whatever reason some objects are randomly disabled in viewport and as such hidden from view and I want to undisable them. Make everything visible. But doing them all individually is just too much work and would be extremely slow.

Is there a script or some hack or hidden blender feature which allows me to set all objects in one collection visible in viewport? Or even all objects visible in all of the blend file? Going back to 2.79 and re-importing with 2.81 compatible viewport settings is too late at this point.

The title claims this question is subjective but I think this is very much a question which has a solution that works and is not about opinion about something. If I wanted to make an opinion I'd say the migration of assets from 2.7x to 2.8x needs more work.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>H</kbd> will hide the selected objects from viewport, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will unhide all objects in viewport.

You can also right-click the collection in the *Outliner*, and select *Visibility* > *Show All Inside*

[image: Menu]

Comment: I'd guess this affects the eye icon. I have the problem with the monitor icon which is and stays disabled for random objects even after doing this

Comment: Press *Enable in Viewports* in that menu instead.

Comment: It is greyed out.

Comment: Welp...in that case, you might want to press Ctrl+Space to fullscreen the *Outliner*, press and hold on one of the unchecked display icons, then run your mouse down the entire column. I don't have any other solution atm :/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is uncheck and then check the collection that you are having difficulties with.

Comment: This does not work. I hold shift when doing it which is what I read should do it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/71eb5c35sfm354o/2020-01-01%2022-26-36.mp4?dl=0

Comment: It sure does work, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you make <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>  on the "disable in viewport" icon of the collection, it applies it on everything in the collection, then redo it, and everything goes back to visible.